# My Timer using AngularJS is not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my controller function

```
setInterval(function () {
var d = new Date();
var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
var fiveMin = 60 * 1;
var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin;
var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
//console.log(result);
var timerObj= {
    timer : result
}
$scope.timerArray = timerObj;
if (timeleft === 1) { 

    $scope.statusDetails = $scope.reset;


    $scope.timeDetails();
    $scope.get_dbStatus();
    $scope.get_sosStatus();
    $scope.get_cepStatus();
    $scope.get_taskStatus();
    $scope.get_mqStatus();
    $scope.get_mrStatus();
    $scope.get_dmStatus();

}
$scope.$apply();
```

},500);

This is my html page

```
<table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5">
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
                                        Version
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="col-lg-1 col-sm-3">
                                        Status
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
                                        Contact Info
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="status in statusDetails">
                                    <td>{{status.title}}</td>
                                    <td>{{status.apiVersion}}</td>
                                    <td><img ng-src="../public/tcup/images/{{status.status}}.png"/></td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Timer and all the things are working fine.But each time timer gets expired and the list gets refreshed the updated list appends to the previous list.

Comment: Please change setInterval to $Intervel

Answer (score 2):

You need to kick off new digest cycle because Angular doesn't know you changed something:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
    var fiveMin = 60 * 2;
    var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin;
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
    //console.log(result);
    var timerObj = {
        timer: result
    }
    $scope.timerArray = timerObj;
    console.log("timer...........");
    console.log($scope.timerArray.timer);

    $scope.$apply(); // <--- apply changes to models
}, 500);
```

Comment: Glad to heat it. Feel free to accept one of the answers, the one with `$interval` is also correct.

Comment: one question-"I want to call a another functon after the time expires how can i do that"

Comment: you need to `clearTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout

Comment: using clearTimeout() or clearInterval() it stops the timer rather than resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setInterval`, use `$interval` to run digest cycle for you, after function execution completed.

**Code**

```
$interval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
    var fiveMin = 60 * 2;
    var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin;
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
    //console.log(result);
    var timerObj = {
        timer: result
    }
    $scope.timerArray = timerObj;
    console.log("timer...........");
    console.log($scope.timerArray.timer);
}, 500)
```

**Edit 1**

To call method after interval gets completed you need to call that inside its promise chain, you could restrict you `$interval` to call it specified amount of time by adding 3rd parameter which will run `$interval` function that amount of time.

**Code**

```
var interval = $interval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
    var fiveMin = 60 * 2;
    var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin;
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
    //console.log(result);
    var timerObj = {
        timer: result
    }
    $scope.timerArray = timerObj;
    console.log("timer...........");
    console.log($scope.timerArray.timer);
}, 500, 10);

interval.then(function(){
    //this code will execute after interval completion
    //you could call any scope method from here
});
```

**Edit 2**

If you call your callback function only once then you should not rely on `$interval` , better you could use `$timeout` instead `$interval`, It will run only once.

**Code**

```
var timeout = $timeout(function() {
    $scope.statusDetails = [];
    $scope.timeDetails();
    $scope.get_dbStatus();
    $scope.get_sosStatus();
    $scope.get_cepStatus();
    $scope.get_taskStatus();
    $scope.get_mqStatus();
    $scope.get_mrStatus();
    $scope.get_dmStatus();
}, 120000);
timeout.then(function() {
    $scope.repeat()
});
```

**Edit 3**

Basically you will need to add one method which will call on the button click using `callInterval` which will start the `$interval` & inside that we will maintain `intervalPromise` variable which will check if interval already exists then it will `cancel` that it interval & then it will create a new interval

**Code**

```
var intervalPromise;

$scope.callInterval = function() {
    if (intervalPromise) //remove interval if already exists
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
    intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
        //..your existing code here
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: one question-"I want to call a another functon after the time expires how can i do that"

Comment: @sanmoypaul `$interval` will run after each `500` milliseconds, for running for number of times you could pass 3rd option as count like `$interval(function () {//code here
}, 500, 10)` as second parameter is 10 It will run interval 10 times, to run it only once use `$timeout`..see my update in answer

Comment: $scope.repeat = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
   $scope.statusDetails = [];
   $scope.timeDetails();
   $scope.get_dbStatus();
   $scope.get_sosStatus();
   $scope.get_cepStatus();
   $scope.get_taskStatus();
   $scope.get_mqStatus();
   $scope.get_mrStatus();
   $scope.get_dmStatus();
  }, 120000)
 }

I want to call this function after the timelimit of 2mins gets expired.

Comment: After the timelimit in the count down timer expires $scope.repeat will be called.

Comment: your code would be `var timeout = $timeout(function(){ $scope.statusDetails = []; $scope.timeDetails(); $scope.get_dbStatus(); $scope.get_sosStatus(); $scope.get_cepStatus(); $scope.get_taskStatus(); $scope.get_mqStatus(); $scope.get_mrStatus(); $scope.get_dmStatus(); }, 120000); timeout.then(function(){$scope.repeat()})` try this, youshould use $timeout then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75569/discussion-between-sanmoy-paul-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: @sanmoypaul I can't come on chat, do you have any question?

Comment: yes a bit......

but the list is getting appended everytime.......
I want only the updated list

Comment: @sanmoypaul I don't see place in your update, where you are appending result to result array?

Comment: @sanmoypaul what do you mean by by reset? I didn't get you..Actually interval run forever if you don't specified `count` parameter in it

Comment: Actually there should be button in which timer must get reset when I click on it.

Comment: @sanmoypaul take a look at my updpated answer

Comment: Please see this 
jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9v45oa3g/1